# Where is the 32bit download for latest Ubuntu Desktop?

Tags: downloads

There is literally no download link except for the bittorent file. Can anyone link me the direct download?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here it is: http://releases.ubuntu.com/xenial/ubuntu-16.04-desktop-i386.iso.

For future reference, you can find the ISOs for various architectures at http://releases.ubuntu.com/.